# удаление одинаковых элементов в многомерном массиве

Tags: php, массивы, алгоритм

как удалить одинаковые элементы по определенным ключам, например по ['email'] и [phone], если email и phone равны удалить запись в обоих массивах вне зависимости от содержания остальных элементов.

первый массив

```
array(15) {
  [0]=>
  array(7) {
    ["email"]=>
    string(9) "dawwadwad"
    ["phone"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["master_id"]=>
    int(4)
    ["name"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["company"]=>
    string(9) "wadadwawd"
    ["post"]=>
    string(9) "wadadwwad"
    ["base_name"]=>
    string(16) "test_base_name_1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(7) {
    ["email"]=>
    string(16) "wadwad@awdwad.lz"
    ["phone"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["master_id"]=>
    int(2)
    ["name"]=>
    string(6) "awdwad"
    ["company"]=>
    string(6) "awdwad"
    ["post"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["base_name"]=>
    string(16) "test_base_name_1"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(7) {
    ["email"]=>
    string(13) "awdwad@Awd.kz"
    ["phone"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["master_id"]=>
    int(5)
    ["name"]=>
    string(6) "awdawd"
    ["company"]=>
    string(6) "awdwad"
    ["post"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["base_name"]=>
    string(16) "test_base_name_1"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(7) {
    ["email"]=>
    string(22) "awdwad@Awd.kzadwwaddwa"
    ["phone"]=>
    string(9) "awdwadwda"
    ["master_id"]=>
    int(8)
    ["name"]=>
    string(12) "awdawdawdwad"
    ["company"]=>
    string(6) "awdwad"
    ["post"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["base_name"]=>
    string(16) "test_base_name_1"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(7) {
    ["email"]=>
    string(11) "max@spc.com"
    ["phone"]=>
    string(12) "+77764086666"
    ["master_id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["name"]=>
    string(3) "max"
    ["company"]=>
    string(2) "CS"
    ["post"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["base_name"]=>
    string(16) "test_base_name_1"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(7) {
    ["email"]=>
    string(13) "jeka@gruz.com"
    ["phone"]=>
    string(12) "+77777777777"
    ["master_id"]=>
    int(2)
    ["name"]=>
    string(8) "Жека"
    ["company"]=>
    string(9) "123вфы"
    ["post"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["base_name"]=>
    string(16) "test_base_name_1"
  }
  [6]=>
  array(7) {
    ["email"]=>
    string(13) "max@gruz.com"
    ["phone"]=>
    string(12) "+77778888888"
    ["master_id"]=>
    int(2)
    ["name"]=>
    string(8) "Макс"
    ["company"]=>
    string(8) "Груз"
    ["post"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["base_name"]=>
    string(16) "test_base_name_2"
  }
  [7]=>
  array(7) {
    ["email"]=>
    string(16) "wadwad@awdwad.lz"
    ["phone"]=>
    string(9) "awdwadwda"
    ["master_id"]=>
    int(2)
    ["name"]=>
    string(6) "awdwad"
    ["company"]=>
    string(6) "awdwad"
    ["post"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["base_name"]=>
    string(16) "test_base_name_1"
  }
  [8]=>
  array(7) {
    ["email"]=>
    string(13) "awdwad@Awd.kz"
    ["phone"]=>
    string(9) "awdwadwda"
    ["master_id"]=>
    int(5)
    ["name"]=>
    string(6) "awdawd"
    ["company"]=>
    string(6) "awdwad"
    ["post"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["base_name"]=>
    string(16) "test_base_name_1"
  }
  [9]=>
  array(7) {
    ["email"]=>
    string(22) "lyubitelev@hotmail.com"
    ["phone"]=>
    string(12) "+77764086666"
    ["master_id"]=>
    int(7)
    ["name"]=>
    string(22) "lyubitelev maxim"
    ["company"]=>
    string(3) "spc"
    ["post"]=>
    string(8) "director"
    ["base_name"]=>
    string(16) "test_base_name_2"
  }
  [10]=>
  array(7) {
    ["email"]=>
    string(12) "test@test.ru"
    ["phone"]=>
    string(11) "89039000000"
    ["master_id"]=>
    int(5001)
    ["name"]=>
    string(27) "Иванов Петр"
    ["company"]=>
    string(14) "Тэглайн"
    ["post"]=>
    string(14) "Уборщик"
    ["base_name"]=>
    string(16) "test_base_name_2"
  }
  [11]=>
  array(7) {
    ["email"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["phone"]=>
    string(10) "9059525482"
    ["master_id"]=>
    NULL
    ["name"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["company"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["post"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["base_name"]=>
    string(16) "test_base_name_2"
  }
  [12]=>
  array(7) {
    ["email"]=>
    string(13) "test@test2.ru"
    ["phone"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["master_id"]=>
    NULL
    ["name"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["company"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["post"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["base_name"]=>
    string(16) "test_base_name_2"
  }
  [13]=>
  array(7) {
    ["email"]=>
    string(11) "max@spc.com"
    ["phone"]=>
    string(12) "+77764086666"
    ["master_id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["name"]=>
    string(3) "max"
    ["company"]=>
    string(3) "spc"
    ["post"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["base_name"]=>
    string(16) "test_base_name_2"
  }
  [14]=>
  array(7) {
    ["email"]=>
    string(13) "jeka@gruz.com"
    ["phone"]=>
    string(12) "+77777777777"
    ["master_id"]=>
    int(2)
    ["name"]=>
    string(8) "Жека"
    ["company"]=>
    string(8) "Груз"
    ["post"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["base_name"]=>
    string(16) "test_base_name_2"
  }
}
```

второй массив

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(7) {
    ["email"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["phone"]=>
    string(10) "9059525482"
    ["master_id"]=>
    NULL
    ["name"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["company"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["post"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["base_name"]=>
    string(16) "test_base_name_2"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(7) {
    ["email"]=>
    string(13) "jeka@gruz.com"
    ["phone"]=>
    string(12) "+77777777777"
    ["master_id"]=>
    int(2)
    ["name"]=>
    string(8) "Жека"
    ["company"]=>
    string(8) "Груз"
    ["post"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["base_name"]=>
    string(16) "test_base_name_2"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(7) {
    ["email"]=>
    string(13) "max@gruz.com"
    ["phone"]=>
    string(12) "+77778888888"
    ["master_id"]=>
    int(2)
    ["name"]=>
    string(8) "Макс"
    ["company"]=>
    string(8) "Груз"
    ["post"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["base_name"]=>
    string(16) "test_base_name_2"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(7) {
    ["email"]=>
    string(11) "max@spc.com"
    ["phone"]=>
    string(12) "+77764086666"
    ["master_id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["name"]=>
    string(3) "max"
    ["company"]=>
    string(3) "spc"
    ["post"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["base_name"]=>
    string(16) "test_base_name_2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь функцией `array_udiff()`, она вернет элменты первого массива, которых нет во втором. Затем вызовите ее еще раз с аргументами наоборот.

функцию компаратор можно определить как-то так

```
$cmp = function($a, $b){
         return strcmp("{$a['email']}-{$a['phone']}", "{$b['email']}-{$b['phone']}");
      }
```

и соединить результат

```
$result = array_merge(
            array_udiff($arr1, $arr2, $cmp),
            array_udiff($arr2, $arr1, $cmp)
    );
```

Если вам не надо сливать результат, то просто

```
$arr1 = array_udiff($arr1, $arr2, $cmp);  
$arr2 = ....
```

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать ...

Comment: $cmp - это Callback-функция которую необходимо передать в array_udiff()?

Comment: @teran поправьте опечатку - название функции `strcmp`

Comment: @MaximLyubitelev да

Comment: @Jigius поправил, спасибо.

Comment: @teran а так можно? `foreach ($items_selection_attributes1 as $key1 => $arr1)
        {
            foreach ($items_selection_attributes2 as $key2 => $arr2)
            {
                if ($arr1['email'] === $arr2['email'] && $arr1['phone'] === $arr2['phone'])
                {
                    unset($items_selection_attributes1[$key1]);
                }
            }
        }`

Comment: @MaximLyubitelev можно по всякому. Если у вас уже есть какой-то код, который по некоторой причине не работает, и вы хотите в этом разобраться, то приведите его в вопросе. А так обычно когда элементы из массива удаляются, то перебирают его с конца. Но `unset` вам ведь надо сделать в обоих массивах тут?

Comment: нет, не обязательно в обоих, этот код я написал пока не было ответов на вопрос, и хочу понять что лучше? =)

Comment: @MaximLyubitelev лучше то, что понятнее.

Comment: @teran спасибо =)